# Highcharts version 7.1.1 how to offline-exporting PDF with amd modules

Tags: highcharts, requirejs, amd, export-to-pdf, offline-mode

How to export a chart (Highcharts) with offline-exporting to pdf **using amd modules**?
Require the jsPDF module throws "sometime" a requirejs mismatched error or messed up the callback references of other requires.

Question Highcharts Forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=41929&sid=5178a78a6547d8fb14769a85392b276c

```js
var chart;
require(['highcharts', 'highcharts/modules/exporting', 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting', 'jsPDF', 'svg2pdf'], function(Highcharts, a, b, jsPDF, svg2pdf) {
    window.jsPDF = jsPDF.default;
    window.svg2pdf = svg2pdf;
    chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    exporting: {
      libURL: 'https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/lib'
    },

    series: [{
      data: [3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
    }]

  });
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.js"></script>

    <script>
      require.config({
        packages: [{
          name: 'highcharts',
          main: 'highcharts',
          location: 'https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1'
        }],
        paths: {
          'jsPDF': 'https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/lib/jspdf',
          'svg2pdf': 'https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/lib/svg2pdf'
        }
      });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zbc149wh/2/

Thank you

Comment: seems to be a known problem of jsPDF. Issue is though closed, but maybe not 100% solved: https://github.com/yWorks/jsPDF/issues/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from jsPDF:
https://github.com/yWorks/jsPDF

I set a name to all define statements, so there is no more anonymous module definitions.
Now it is working.

Example line 3

Before:

```
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
```

After:

```
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define('jsPDF', ['exports'], factory) :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup offline export like this

```
exporting: {
        chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    }
```

Your code forked: https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/fs03ou4k/7/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.fallbackToExportServer

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

Comment: Thank you Hien. I know that this is working. But that's not what I want. I need to load the highcharts modules with requirejs (as amd modules). And unfortunately this is not working. If window.jsPDF and window.svg2pdf are not defined the module offline-exporting insert script tags in the dom. This doesn't work if the modules are loaded with require. Load jsPDF with require doesn't work to (require mismatch and still not defined).